# Problems FTPing FROM Azure to another FTP site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, ftp

I've tried using FtpWebRequest and EnterpriseDT.Net.Ftp on an Azure website where I want to pass a byte array from a FileUpload to another FTP site.

This works on local servers and hence will work on a VM but cannot get it working on an Azure website.  Admittedly we're trying to avoid the costs of adding a VM or an additional Azure storage account.

It seems the port is blocked on Azure, yet it is open to us on local servers.

`[IOException: Failed to connect to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:21 within timeout 120000 ms]
   EnterpriseDT.Net.StandardSocket.InternalConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, Int32 timeout) +272
   EnterpriseDT.Net.StandardSocket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP, Int32 timeout) +350
   EnterpriseDT.Net.Ftp.FTPControlSocket.ConnectSocket(BaseSocket socket, String address, Int32 port) +66
   EnterpriseDT.Net.Ftp.FTPControlSocket.Initialize(BaseSocket sock, String remoteHost, Int32 controlPort, Int32 timeout, Encoding encoding) +57
   EnterpriseDT.Net.Ftp.FTPClient.Connect(String remoteHost, Int32 controlPort, Int32 timeout) +407
   EnterpriseDT.Net.Ftp.FTPClient.Connect() +43
   EnterpriseDT.Net.Ftp.FTPConnection.Connect() +456
   XXXXX.XXXXX.XXX.XXXXX.FtpUpload(String Id, FileUpload file, String ftpServer, String ftpUsername, String ftpPass, String domainName) +371`

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished via .net FtpWebRequest or a third party library?

Comment: Some clarification questions: Are you using Azure Websites as source? Are you trying to FTP to an Azure Website as destination?

Comment: Thanks Amit.  An Azure website is the source and a different Azure website is the destination.

Answer (score 0):

The FTP port (21) is blocked for an Azure website directly, if you use: ftp://{sitename}.azurewebsites.net, to get the proper FTP profile for that website you need to download it's publishing settings, there you'll find the address, user name and password.

Information on getting the publish profile is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/06/26/deploying-windows-azure-website-using-visual-studio-web-publish-wizard.aspx

I would also recommend you use the VFS endpoint of your scm site (https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net) to upload files, this way you use https protocol which is more reliable.

The VFS api:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#vfs

More about your scm site:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2014/03/04/windows-azure-websites-online-tools-you-should-know-about.aspx

Comment: Thank you Amit.  Unfortunately due to tight timelines, I've had to group the sites into one and upload directly.  I was using the publish profile already, but did not seem to work.  I'll certainly keep your answer in mind should this occur again, and will feedback here.